# Data Sources (ODBC) hangs when trying to create a new database connection

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, odbc

When I try to create a new database connection, the Data Sources (ODBC) programs hangs or takes a very long time to find the list of available SQL Servers.

This only happens when there are other computers on the network, when my machine (a standard Windows 7 laptop) is alone, it works just fine.

[image: ODBC Window - hangs when I try to select SQL Server]

My question is: **What should I look for in terms of SQL server or ODBC configurations that will take away this random behaviour**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not direct answer to your question, but in Server field you can write in `ServerAddress` or `ServerAddress\InstanceName`:

[image: write address]

So when you know this value don't do server discovery (expand the list). List all Sql Servers in (large) network usually takes long time.